# python derivative in python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7

> Finite difference is a numerical method to approximate a derivative.
>   There are mainly three types of finite difference method: central,
>   forward and backward.
>
> In this question, I will introduce central difference method. we can
>   approximate `f '(x)` by: `f'(x)=(f(x+h)-f(x-h))/2h`. Write a code to
>   calculate the first derivative of sin(x) at `x=0` with `h=1`, `0.1,
>   0.01 and 0.001`. Also compare the result with `cos(0)` (to use function “cos()”, you should import “math” first).
>
> Draw a graph to compare the result of different h value, x axis is the
>   value of h and y1 axis is the calculated first derivative of `sin(x)`
>   and y2 is the result of `cos(0)`.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import math

def f(x):
    return sin(x)

def derivative(0,h=1)
    deriv = (f(x + h) - f(x - h))/ 2 * h
    return round(deriv, 0)

print "f'(x)=", derivative(0)
```

Can anyone give me some suggestions?

Comment: `Write a code to calculate the first derivative...` What have you tried so far? Please provide a minimal working sample code, else your question will be flagged for not providing one.

Answer (score 0):

Your main problem is you are dividing by `2 * h`, this means divide by `2`, then multiply by `h`. You need to divide by `(2 * h)`. You might have learned the [BODMAS rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3510/what-does-the-term-bodmas-mean) in school.

```
>>> 12 / 2 * 3
18
```

That divides 12 by 2 to get 6, then multiplies 6 by 3. If you group `(2 * 3)` using parentheses, the whole multiplication operation will be evaluated first:

```
>>> 12 / (2 * 3)
2
```

Fixed code:

```
def f_dash(f, x, h):
    return (f(x + h) - f(x - h)) / (2 * h)

>>> from math import sin, cos
>>> f_dash(f=sin, x=0, h=0.1)
0.9983341664682815

>>> f_dash(sin, 0, 0.001)
0.9999998333333416
```

Comment: File "./55.py", line 5
    def derivative(0,h=1)
                          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: @penny you're missing a colon `def function():`. [Colons introduce blocks](http://stackoverflow.com/a/215676/1084416).